# Modify text being inserted into GTK TextBuffer

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3

I have a `TextView` and I want to automatically convert all typed, pasted, etc. text to uppercase, is it possible? I tried adding a `bufferInsertText` handler and inserting text from there by myself, but this error message kept popping up:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid text buffer iterator: either the iterator
is uninitialized, or the characters/pixbufs/widgets in the buffer
have been modified since the iterator was created.
You must use marks, character numbers, or line numbers to preserve
a position across buffer modifications.
You can apply tags and insert marks without invalidating your
iterators, but any mutation that affects 'indexable' buffer contents
(contents that can be referred to by character offset) will
invalidate all outstanding iterators
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's get the `TextBuffer` from `TextView`:

```hs
buffer ← G.get textView textViewBuffer
```

Now, using an `IORef`, we can get the ID of `bufferInsertText` signal we'll be connecting to, because we'll need it later:

```hs
sigInsertIdRef ← newIORef undefined
sigInsertId ← buffer `on` bufferInsertText $ 
                handler buffer sigInsertIdRef
writeIORef sigInsertIdRef sigInsertId
```

Actual insertion of text happens in TextBuffer's default handler, which fires after our handler. Therefore, here's what we should do in the handler:

- Temporarily disable the custom handler (we can do it using its `ConnectId`).
- Ask the buffer to insert our modified text, which would now go straight to the default handler.
- Enable the custom handler again.
- Stop the original signal from going further the chain and firing the default handler.

And here's the code which does precisely that:

```hs
handler :: TextBuffer → IORef → TextIter → String → IO ()
handler buffer sigIdRef iter str = do
  sigId ← readIORef sigIdRef
  signalBlock sigId
  textBufferInsert buffer iter (map toUpper str)
  signalUnblock sigId
  signalStopEmission buffer "insert-text"
```